# ios App hangs in ionic, while running using xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, freeze

After building our ionic app using :

```
cordova build ios
```

I ran it in my iphone 6 using xcode. It works great. Now when I kill the app in device and click on the app icon to launch it from the device it takes longer to launch, and stays in a hanged state, unable to even inspect it using safari.

(No way related to this question, still) there occurs no issues even if the app is killed in android. It works just fine.

Has anyone experienced such an issues? Is there a way out to it?

Comment: Are you executing some logic at startup? Please show us some of your code.

Comment: No, it's actually an ionic app...

Comment: See this... https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/iphone-froze-after-installing-ionic-app-through-xcode/16924 the issue actually exists, but when tried out with Diawi, there was no such issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is actually discussed in [Ionic Forums](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/iphone-froze-after-installing-ionic-app-through-xcode/16924). It's not of logic, but when you run via Xcode, there are controls of xcode associated to the build. So once we kill the app and restart it, the controls of Xcode are disconnected, so there are 2 issues:

**1)** Xcode maintains some active connection which is used for debugging purposes, while launching app via xcode.

**2)** If that connection is broken - to mess with the phone Xcode is expected to throw an error about a process being killed or something but to block the main-thread. But that doesn't happen.

**3)** It has something to do with how the XCode debugger works. Either the PC or the device is trying to poll each other constantly and if we deviate from what they are expecting it causes problems on the iPhone.

Although xcode detects if the phone is disconnected, but it still fails to detect if the app was killed